# Detect Device Rotation/Movement in iOS sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, accelerometer, panorama-control

I want to detect the device movement & Rotation just like when we are taking the `Panorama Picture.`

I want to `move the Image` same as the `arrow while we capture Panorama Image.`

There are many apps who uses this functionality but I can't able to find anything for this.

Help me to solve this.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use motion sensor in iphone ,But it wont give you the accurate result.

[What motion does iPhone SDK give exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604534/what-motion-does-iphone-sdk-give-exactly)

But i am providing the motion sensor delegate methods code from this below link.

[How do I detect when someone shakes an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150446/how-do-i-detect-when-someone-shakes-an-iphone)

Verify this link you can have answer from this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. But as you said, it is vary hard to measure the displacement. But there are many apps which are measuring the displacement for panoramic image.

Comment: Please check edited answer, in which i provided second link it may be helpfull

Comment: Thanks  but i don't want to detect the shake motion