# How do I do location tracking on iPhone more efficiently than leaving GPS on all the time?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, gps

I am working on a location app for the iPhone (iOS 6), that constantly sends accurate location information to a web service.  I have it set-up so that the app sends a location packet every minute (as long as there has been a significant change in position).  This part of the app is working great (as a background task), but as you might expect it affects battery life significantly having GPS on all the time (I get about 6 hours which isn't too bad given I'm used to plugging in my phone in the car and when at home so I can get through the day OK, but I need to stretch this out to at least 16 hours to be practical).

What I would like to do is turn the GPS off when the phone indicates that it hasn't moved significantly for a while.  This is trivial to do using the GPS data itself.  However, with the GPS off, what might I use as a trigger to turn it back on again, and restart location posting?  I could just turn it off when it is sensed that no new position has been generated for say 5 minutes, and then check the position X minutes later to see if it has changed, and act accordingly.  Or maybe I could use the accelerometer in some clever way, or some other sensor, to trigger turning on GPS again.

Given that travel time is often a small part of the day, it makes sense to minimize GPS activity when at home, or in the office... but how to do that reliably?

Comment: In case anyone is interested an example of the output of the app as it currently stands is: https://motion.blob.core.windows.net/kml-motion/4a03a463-821a-4cd5-b4ba-a0f71aaa6c3e.kml.  This is a KML file that can be opened and viewed directly in Google Earth.

Comment: i looked at your kml file, but now i can only look at the plain text file. one Tipp: use less digits after komma, youn dont need a position to have a resolution of 1/1000 cm

Comment: Thanks for the tip AlexWien - have added some rounding.

Comment: There really isn't an answer that addresses the problem.  It seems that at present I am already doing everything to maximize battery life... So the answer is really within the hardware - lower energy GPS, or higher storage batteries.  Both will come in time.

Comment: In my answer I stated that it is not possible to have both 16h battery and accurate position. And you finally see that it not possible. This is the correct answer, although you wished that there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The model I might contemplate is to use the [standard location service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW7) to get my location, and once I've got that, turn it off and turn on the [significant change location service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW8) which uses far less power. And, once I got a subsequent significant change notification (you might want to disregard the first one as you already had the accurate location), you can turn the standard location service again to get the accurate location (assuming you need that at all ... if you didn't need super accurate location, you'd obviously just use significant change location service from the get-go).

Alternatively, if you're doing that and it's still using too much power, you could turn off location services entirely and then turn it back on after a certain amount of time, but you might lose significant location changes in the interim and if the user isn't moving at all, it will use more power than the above technique in many scenarios.

Comment: Yes, I'm currently using significant change location service, and finding that that is still using too much power.  Your second para gets right to the heart of my dilemma.  That's why I was wondering if there are external-to-GPS triggers that might be combined reliably to turn the location service back on.

Comment: @ProfNimrod Alas, not that I know of. That's precisely what significant change was for. But if even that takes too much power, then some timer-based solution is the only thing I can think of, and that has significant drawbacks itself. I suspect that the only other option, monitoring when you leave a [region](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW13), will draw no less power than significant change service. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but an alternative to using GPS altogether is inertial dead (deduced) reckoning.  This can be achieved using only the accelerometer and gyros (and a bit of clever maths), with GPS once in a while as a check.  I don't know how accurate this approach would be, or what it's impact on battery time would be... I'll let you know when I've implemented it ;-)

Although [Android accelerometer accuracy (Inertial navigation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7829097/android-accelerometer-accuracy-inertial-navigation) seems to suggest it isn't worth the effort, but I think that is using an accelerometer only, and doesn't make use of gyros - the two devices provide different aspects of motion: [Gyroscope vs Accelerometer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089917/gyroscope-vs-accelerometer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're not worried about the loss of precision caused by leaving GPS off for a few minutes, then you might consider leaving it off entirely. The cell tower location mechanism works fine, although it locates to the tower, which may be some way away. But then, in a few minutes, it's easy to travel that far anyway. And the network locator that does cell towers also does wifi networks, with accuracy of 20m or so. And GPS doesn't work indoors anyway. So, leave the GPS off, and leve the network location on, the whole time.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that I am worried about precision in the question... although having a second mode that switches over to network location might be useful - when for example it see battery drop to 25%... interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

my app (under development) runs 8 hours in background recording one fix per second to file. thats enough, it will not get better. you cannot have both, GPS precision and 20 hours of battery. 
6 hours, that may be caused also by server communication (or enabling the device to often).

 But An interesting approach could be the movement sensor, but its a good question how much battery it needs. 
do you know any iphone app which can record precise GPS for far more than 8 hours?
i have never measured, but try MotionX gps, how long they can record.

Comment: What is "akku"?  Is that a foreign language?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the trade between battery and accuracy - guess I'm stuck having to work with the 6-8 hours limitation at the moment... hopefully within a year or so this won't be such a concern with better batteries and more efficient GPS.